# How to copy and install a dll into assembly folder using NSIS on an Windows OS with elevated UAC

Tags: nsis, setup-deployment

I am building an application setup where the installation involves copying and registering Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs into the Windows assembly folder. This process sometimes fails on a Windows 7 system where the UAC is active.Currently, i use the following script in a section:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\bin
File "..\MyFolder\systemfiles\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll
ExecWait '"$R0\RegAsm.exe" Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll'
```

Requesting to kindly provide me some script/solution to successfully copy and register the dll even when the UAC is elevated on a Windows 7 system

Answer (score 0):

All NSIS installers should contain a `RequestExecutionLevel` attribute, it is inspected by Windows Vista and later when UAC is on.

Your installer needs to request administrator privileges when you are installing things in GAC, SxS etc:

```
Outfile RequireAdmin.exe
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Page InstFile

Section
SectionEnd
```